# Why aren't my images loading in compiled .jar file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, path, sfml, jsfml

**Explanation:**
I'm currently programming [game library](https://github.com/FilipeeX/GamerLibrary) in java with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. I'm using [jSFML](https://jsfml.sfmlprojects.org/) as a multimedia library.
I tried rendering a sprite, using jsfml's wiki page, and everything seemed to work fine, so I moved on.

**Problem:**
Later I tried compile the library with a testing game, and realized that sprite of player can't be loaded. When it's running from editor, everything is fine, but if I run it outside of editor, it's not working.
It's giving me this error, what I believe means that file doesn't exist, i don't know:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to load image "C:\src\main\resources\Player.png". Reason : Unable to open file
    at org.jsfml.graphics.Texture.loadFromFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsfml.graphics.Texture.loadFromFile(Unknown Source)
    at filipeex.gamer.library.core.GameRenderer.DisplaySprite(GameRenderer.java:32)
    at filipeex.gamer.library.gameobjects.Player.FrameRender(Player.java:38)
    at filipeex.gamer.library.core.Game.FrameRender(Game.java:118)
    at filipeex.gamer.library.core.Game.InitLoop(Game.java:206)
    at filipeex.gamer.library.core.Game.InitWindow(Game.java:180)
    at filipeex.gamer.library.core.Game.Start(Game.java:52)
    at filipeex.gamer.library.testing.TestingAsUser.main(TestingAsUser.java:29)
```

This is code for loading texture and rendering it to window:

```
GameRenderer.DisplaySprite("/src/main/resources/Player.png", position, rotation);
```

And the method itself:

```
Texture t = new Texture();
t.loadFromFile(Paths.get(path));

Sprite s = new Sprite(t);
s.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
s.setScale(1, 1);
s.setRotation(rotation);

GameWindow.Get().draw(s);
```

**I've already:**

- searched for a lot of similar questions,
- tried every possible solution from them, including adding directory to artifact, didn't work.

Comment: Because the path you have is to the relative location in your uncompiled project!! `src\main\resources\Player.png`. You need to use the classloder.

Comment: You're calling `Texture.loadFromFile`. You don't want it to be from a file - you want it to be from a resource within the jar file. I suspect you want `loadFromStream`, having called `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` or similar.